# Multiprocessing with conditional process spawning in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a mono threaded function that I would like to parallelize. The code is a bit too complex to show you, but here is a modelization of its behaviours

```py
R = list(range(4))

def compute(val):
    res = sum(val)
    if res%2 == 0: #first condition on res
        sleep(0.5) #expansive operation
        if res%4 == 0: #second condition on res
            sleep(0.5) #expansive operation
            return 2
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        return 1

def f_single(idx, val):
    if idx == len(R):
        return 1
    else:
        val = val + [R[idx]]
        ret = compute(val)
        if ret == 1:
            return f_single(idx+1, val)
        else:
            #DISJUNCT
            return f_single(idx+1, val) + f_single(idx+1, val)
```

Basically, each recursion performs an update of the variable `val`, and I may need to perform a double call on certain conditions depending on the result of `compute(val)`, which is an expansive computation.
(Sidenote: this implementation does not scale up to large lists, since I will StackOverflow quite rapidly; the multiprocessing effort is also an excuse to rewrite this code).

Ideally, I would like to spawn a new process for computing the new call to `f_single`.

I started refactoring the code like this:

```py
# list of indices
def process_idxs():
    return list(range(len(R)))
def are_two_path(idx, val):
    val = val + [R[idx]]
    ret = compute(val)
    if ret == 1:
        return False #simulate a "only one path"
    return True #simulate a "two path available"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ret = f_single(0,[])
    now = time()
    idxs = process_idxs()
    # start a job when the job queue is not full
    # when the job is complete, return the results (solvers with call stacks)
    # add the new results to the job queue
    # program terminates when the job queue is done
    # TODO: how to do this?
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=12) as executor:
        for idx in idxs:
            f = executor.submit(are_two_path, idx, val)
            print(f.result())
    print("multi proc: ", time()-now, "s")
```

I don't know how to write my parallelization routine to obtain the same return value than `f_single` (the last few lines are a tentative to do just that).

When looking in [concurrent.future](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor) and [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing), I did not found an easy way to collect the results of computation for the current index, conditionally spawn the process and perform to the next recursion, while passing the updated value of val.

I don't have any shared state, except R which is read-only so it shouldn't be an issue here.

Do you have any suggestions or guides on how to convert f_single to a multiprocessing function?

Comment: First what "does not work" mean (error messages? Traceback?)

Comment: The output result is not the same than the `f_single` one. I'm editing the question to reflect more accurately what I meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to do it is to do the following:

```py
import os
from time import time, sleep
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from queue import Empty

R = list(range(16))
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES = 32
TIMEOUT = 1

def compute(val):
    res = sum(val)
    if res%2 == 0: #first condition on res
        sleep(1) #expansive operation
        if res%4 == 0: #second condition on res
            sleep(1) #expansive operation
            return 2
        else:
            return 1
    else:
        return 1
def are_two_path(idx, val):
    val = val + [R[idx]]
    ret = compute(val)
    if ret == 1:
        return False #simulate a "only one path"
    return True #simulate a "two path available"
def worker(q, r, start_val, start_idx):
    """Worker spawned in a new process, in charge of
    going through the list iteratively.
    Sends a new job to the tasks queue if two path are available
    """
    val = start_val
    for idx in range(start_idx, len(R)+1):
        if idx == len(R):
            r.put(1)
        else:
            result = are_two_path(idx, val)
            if result:
                q.put((idx+1, val+[R[idx]]))
            val = val + [R[idx]]
def overseer():
    """Running in the initial process,
    this function create tasks and results queues,
    maintain the number of current running processes
    and spawn new processes when there is enough room
    """
    tasks = Queue()
    results = Queue()
    init_p = Process(target=worker,
            args=(tasks, results, [], 0))
    init_p.start()
    working = 1
    completed_last_cycle = 0
    while True:
        completed_tasks = results.qsize()
        if working < NUMBER_OF_PROCESSES:
            # if there is enough room in the working queue,
            # spawn a new process and add it
            try:
                (idx, val) = tasks.get(timeout=5)
            except Empty:
                break
            p = Process(target=worker, args=(tasks, results, val, idx))
            p.start()
            working += 1
        if completed_tasks > completed_last_cycle:
            # if some processes terminated during last cycle,
            # update the working counter
            working -= (completed_tasks - completed_last_cycle)
            completed_last_cycle = completed_tasks
    tasks.close()
    tasks.join_thread()
    results.close()
    results.join_thread()
    return results
def test():
    res = overseer()
    print("Number of case splits: ", res.qsize())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    now = time()
    test()
    print("multi proc: ", time()-now, "s")
```